# Consumir REST IONIC3

Tags: ionic, rest, ionic2, ionic3, angular

olá, sou novo na área de Web e Ionic3 e estou com um problema, segui um tutorial para consumir uma API rest, consegui trazer a list com os usuários, porem estou querendo trazer um usuario específico e mostrar na tela, se eu mudo a URL para o usuário ele me mostra esse erro

```
TabCepPage.html:10 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object
'[object Object]' of type 'Leanne Graham'. NgFor only supports binding 
to  Iterables such as Arrays.
```

meu app ta assim:

provider: rest.ts

```
apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  console.log('Hello RestServiceProvider Provider');
}

getUsers() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/users/1').subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}
```

ts da pagina:

```
users: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restProvider: RestProvider) {
  this.getUsers();
}

getUsers() {
  this.restProvider.getUsers()
  .then(data => {
    this.users = data;
    console.log(this.users);
  });
}
```

e no HTML exibo assim:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
  <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
  <p>{{user.email}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: por favor alguem poderia ajudar? estou fazendo um app para uma empresa e meu emprego depende disso!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você olhar o erro com calma ira ver que o Ngfor esta tentando iterar sobre um objeto *'Leanne Graham'* que não há suporte e que é o atributo name retornado pela API. Como você está retornando apenas um objeto, seu html ficará assim:

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
  <h2>{{user?.name}}</h2>
  <p>{{user?.email}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

**Obs**: se você usar o Ctrl + Shift + J, você irá abrir o console do navegador(Chrome), e poderá ver como o objeto está sendo retornado, através dos `console.log()`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo, mas não estou conseguindo exibir ainda, o chrome me reporta esse erro: 

    ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

e esse 

    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: o que aparece no console quando você chama getUsers()? Talvez você terá que pegar o primeiro item do array assim: this.users = data[0];

Comment: olá, eu to tentando pegar o usuário único, não tem array, ele ta pegando isso:

{id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham", username: "Bret", email: "Sincere@april.biz", address: {…}, …}
address
:
{street: "Kulas Light", suite: "Apt. 556", city: "Gwenborough", zipcode: "92998-3874", geo: {…}}
company
:
{name: "Romaguera-Crona", catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net", bs: "harness real-time e-markets"}
email
:
"Sincere@april.biz"
id
:
1
name
:
"Leanne Graham"
phone
:
"1-770-736-8031 x56442"
username
:
"Bret"
website
:
"hildegard.org"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: pois é, isto aqui resolve o seu problema  this.users = data[0]

Comment: eu fiz isso:

getUsers() {
    this.restProvider.getUsers()
    .then(data => {
      this.users = data[0];
      console.log(this.users);
    });
  }

ai aparece ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

e no getusers() ele me retorna Undefined

Comment: editei a resposta, realmente não precisa colocar o [0], me confundi, agora dará certo. O operador ? serve para verificar se os valores estão presentes.

Comment: muito obrigado amigo, só precisei alterar para "users?." ao invés de user, me ajudou bastante, se possível e não fosse incomodo para vc teria algum contato para eu tirar algumas dúvidas em outros problemas com o ionic?

Comment: Boa noite, no meu perfil aqui do stackoverflow tem o meu linkedin, pode entrar em contato comigo por la.